# Gradle: Why plus operator causes dupe strings to concat?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

In my `build.gradle` file in Android Studio, I'm creating a new APK file name with the following:

```
def newApkName = rootProject.name + "-" + variant.versionName + variant.buildType.versionNameSuffix
```

This is causing the following to print out: *app-2.2.0-debug-debug*

However if I do the following instead:

```
def newApkName = rootProject.name + "-" + variant.versionName
newApkName.concat(variant.buildType.versionNameSuffix)
```

It correctly prints out: *app-2.2.0-debug*

I'm new to gradle, so I'm very confused why using the plus operator to concat is causing a dupe string to appear...where as using the concat method doesn't.  Any insight on why this is?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you print out `variant.versionName`, you'll see that `variant.buildType.versionNameSuffix` has already been appended as suffix, which makes sense given `variant.buildType.versionNameSuffix`'s function.

The reason why

```
def newApkName = rootProject.name + "-" + variant.versionName
newApkName.concat(variant.buildType.versionNameSuffix)
```

produces different result is because Gradle(Groovy) Strings are immutable, same as Java, and since the result of the concat is discarded, `newApkName` remains to be the result of `rootProject.name + "-" + variant.versionName` only.

Therefore the correct statement should just be:

```
def newApkName = rootProject.name + "-" + variant.versionName
```

Comment: Wow. Big duh moment for me there.  Thanx!

Comment: Could also do `def newApkName = "${rootProject.name}-${variant.versionName}"`. To me, that's easier on the eyes.